# Deprecated preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead

Tags: php, regex

Apologies for asking this question again. I have seen some of the other answers to this question but to be frank I'm so bad at regexing I couldn't figure out how to exactly use those solutions to fix my own problem

Here is my code that I'm having trouble with.

```
$features = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!es', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $features);
```

Comment: What specific trouble?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to serialize or manipulate a serialized var?

Answer (score 0):

```
$features = preg_replace_callback('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!s', function($c) {
    return serialize($c[2]);
}, $features);
```

When-/Where-ever the pattern matches in the source ($features in the example) the callback is invoked and all captures are passed as an array ($c in the example).
$c[0] is the complete match, $c[1] the first sub-capture (the string that maches `\d+`), $c[2] the seconds sub-capture (the string that matches `.*?`).
The complete match is replaced by whatever the callback returns.
Take a look at this example:

```
<?php
echo "\r\n\r\n-------- example #1 --------\r\n";
$src = '1a2b3c';
$result = preg_replace_callback('!\d!', function($c) {
    cprint($c);
    $retval = $c[0]+22;
    echo '  cb returns: ', $retval, "\r\n";
    return $retval;
}, $src);
echo 'result: ', $result, "\r\n";


echo "\r\n\r\n-------- example #2 --------\r\n";
$src = '1a2b3c4a5b6';
$result = preg_replace_callback('!(\d)a(\d)!', function($c) {
    cprint($c);

    $retval = sprintf('%dA%d', $c[1]+22, $c[2]+33);
    echo '  cb returns: ', $retval, "\r\n";
    return $retval;
}, $src);
echo 'result: ', $result, "\r\n";



function cprint(array $c) {
    echo 'callback invoked
  $c=', preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', var_export($c, true)), "\r\n";
}
```

prints

```
-------- example #1 --------
callback invoked
  $c=array ( 0 => '1', )
  cb returns: 23
callback invoked
  $c=array ( 0 => '2', )
  cb returns: 24
callback invoked
  $c=array ( 0 => '3', )
  cb returns: 25
result: 23a24b25c


-------- example #2 --------
callback invoked
  $c=array ( 0 => '1a2', 1 => '1', 2 => '2', )
  cb returns: 23A35
callback invoked
  $c=array ( 0 => '4a5', 1 => '4', 2 => '5', )
  cb returns: 26A38
result: 23A35b3c26A38b6
```

Comment: Could you accompany your answer with a few lines explaining how it works, since the OP explicitly says he is "so bad at regexing" :) ?

Comment: Thank you very much that does appear to have solved the problem perfectly so much appreciated. A Morten Jensen says a little explaination would be great. Thanks